# SQL Server - Insert value in string at dynamic position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple entries in the "Test1" column

These are for example:

```
123ABCsignal2342
23ABsignal234signal
ABBSDsignal2signal
```

I want to update the entries like this:

```
123ABC.signal2342  
23AB.signal234signal 
ABBSD.signal2signal
```

The position for inserting the dot (.) is always in a different place and is signed by the expression "signal". Even if "signal" occurs several times, the point should be inserted only once at the beginning.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: use [charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the first occurrence and then use [stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the dot in.

Comment: SQL operates on rows, not substrings. What you ask is replacing one string with another, not INSERTing

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @strs varchar(50) = '23ABsignal234signal'
SELECT STUFF(@strs
               , CHARINDEX('signal', @strs)
               , LEN('signal')
               , '.signal')
```

> OR

As Suggested Squirrel

```
Declare @strs varchar(50) = '23ABsignal234signal'
SELECT STUFF(@strs, CHARINDEX('signal', @strs), 0, '.')
```

Comment: you can simply `SELECT STUFF(@strs, CHARINDEX('signal', @strs) , 0, '.')`

Comment: @Roshan and Squirrel. Thanks that works perfect.